# Measure user activity time duration on android using facebook analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics, facebook-analytics

I am creating a media stream service which streams media(e.g. audio) over internet. I want to measure how much time is user spending listen the audio using facebook analytics.

I can measure user's session time using facebook analytics using session length provided by facebook.

How can I measure users' time spent on listening the audios?

Answer (score 0):

Is this mobile App or Web?
One way to do it is using one of our SDKs to send custom event which represent audio play time:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events

Above event can be a "beackon" - you send from client or server every X seconds. Another option is you send single event (assuming you can detect when audio is paused / stopped accurately) with value number which represents overall play time in seconds.

Comment: I am using android app. In case of measuring paused/stopped, it will be difficult to measure time if the user kills the application using recent task manager.